# changing the color of p elements with .click(function)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the color of some p elements when they're clicked and while they're in that state, but when another p is clicked I need to change the color of the previous p element back to normal, just wondering how it's possible to do that.

thanks

```
$('.slide span p').click(function() {
    var p =$(this);
    p.css('color','#999');

           //not working with :not()
            p:not().css('#color','#ffffff');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
$('.slide span p').click(function() {
        var p =$(this);
        $('.slide span p').css("color", "#ffffff");
        p.css('color','#999');
});
```

Or you can add and remove css classes, allowing you to target the active P for more effects:

```
$('.slide span p').click(function() {
        $('.slide span p').removeClass('activePara');
        $(this).addClass('activePara');
});
```

Of course, you have to add a css style for activePara somewhere.
I prefer the second approach because the rules for display are kept with the rest of the css, and you now have a class on the active para, allowing you to add more styling, or more jquery effects.

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you want...

```
$('.slide span p').click(function() {
  //CHANGE ALL PARAGRAPHS WHO HAVE THIS CLICK EVENT BACK TO THE NORMAL COLOR
  $(".slide span p").css("color","#FFF");

  //APPLY YOUR SPECIAL COLOR HERE TO THIS PARTICULAR P
  $(this).css("color","#999");
});
```

Give that a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("p").not(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler, first change all p elements to normal, and then change the clicked element to its special color.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you may go:

1. Loop through all Ps
2. Check the current color of each p
3. Use if else to check if previous color apply new else apply previos.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.slide span p').click(function() {
        $("p").css("color","black");
        $(this).css("color","red");
    });
});
```